# Hacer un reroll de dados?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy empezando en Kotlin, y es posible que la solucion se muy obvia, pero estoy intentando hacer un "rerol" de dados, donde tu elijes a partir de que numero quieres hacer el reroll con los resultados de los dados. He probado varias cosas, y siempre se me cierra la aplicacion al momento de sacar esos numeros.
este es el codigo del reroll:

```
 private fun d4Reroll(){
        if(editTextNumberRerollPlus.text.toString().isEmpty()){
         Toast.makeText(this, "you must put a reroll number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
        }else{
            val rerollNumber = editTextNumberRerollPlus.text.toString().toInt()
            var d4 = d4Result.text.toString().toInt()
          val d42 = listOf<Int>(d4)
          val filterNot = d42.filterNot { it < rerollNumber }
            val mutableList = mutableListOf<Int>()
            for(it in filterNot)
                mutableList.add((1..4).random())
            d4Result.text = mutableList.toString()
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Y controlaste el LogCat al momento en que se te cierra la aplicación?

Comment: 2021-11-24 15:46:55.049 17439-17439/com.example.lab2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lab2, PID: 17439
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]"

Comment: Estás queriendo convertir una numeración separada por comas a `Int`. Eso te lanzará la `NumberFormatException`. Tendrás que parsear por tu cuenta el `String` para obtener cada número por separado antes de convertirlos a `Int` individualmente.